# Is it possible to do social authentication from the server side on mobile seamlessly?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, godot, social-authentication

I'm creating a mobile game using Godot for IOS and Android, firebase and facebook plugins are available for the android version only. Therefore it's not an option because I want to a cross platform solution.

I have a websockets server, I could use that to do the authentication (as a client to call facebook API). My only question is that would the user experience / process be the same? I think not, The user would have to sign in from the browser correct? He won't  be able to just use the gmail installed on his phone or facebook, is that true?